# specifics on modal playing, or emphasizing an underlying chord

Tags: chord-theory, improvisation, solos, tonal, modal

i've been reading a lot about modal playing, perhaps that which is derived from modal Jazz. the sources i've been reading & watching seem split about the notes/scale & which to emphasize.

some sources say to play modally, one must emphasize the root of the given mode or the underlying chord, while basically playing "willy-nilly" the corresponding parent Major scale. So, [a aeolian] would emphasize the note [A], while playing whatever else within the CMaj scale, all the while an [a minor] chord is playing underneath.

others say that the half-step intervals, which are derived from the parent scale & are shifted or "adjusted" for each relative mode, along with further emphasis on the modal tonic, is what "defines" the mode, while the underlying chord is playing underneath.

perhaps the type of 3rd is necessary, to define Major or minor-quality mode? maybe the 3rd is played only the melody, not in the chord, so to sound more "ambiguous", or quartal?

at this point, i feel like the latter is the most suitable. for example, if an [a minor] chord is playing underneath & i'm simply wanting to imply a standard [aeolian] or [a aeolian] "sound", i would put heavier emphasis on the notes [A], [B], [C], [E] & [F]. This is because [A] is the root & the other notes form the half-step intervals (ie; 1 - 2 - b3 - 5 - b6 in aeolian)

Also, the underlying [a minor] chord, or perhaps more "modal" voicings such as [A sus2], would contain some of the half-step intervals, so a melody over the top could emphasize the other half-step note, so to "rub against" the tone in the chord?

Am I overthinking this? Is there a more refined way of thinking, when it comes to "modal" playing & emphasizing certain notes over a chord to produce a "flavor"?

Comment: I have the impression you're confusing chord-scale relationships with modal playing. In the latter case, the whole point is to use a single mode/scale to play *across* chord changes without adjusting to each individual chord. Chord-scale playing is where the mode/scale is adjusted to each chord as it appears.

Comment: I think you're over-thinking it. Or maybe just thinking in the wrong order. It's not clear what your question is. That said, I wouldn't *try* to "play modally", at least not from a theory perspective. Instead, work on what sounds right along with different chord progressions. If you think about the chords you're playing with and find the notes that sound good with those chords, you'll probably discover that the way you view the notes you're playing isn't exactly a major or minor scale. Instead, you might find you prefer a flat seven or sharp four. Then you're using modes the natural way.

Comment: Without knowing what you're actually doing, I'd say, too much reading and watching, too little playing. For every 10 hours of playing, you're allowed to have 1 hour of browsing the internet. Ok?

Comment: @ToddWilcox - your comment is the basis for a good answer - go for it!